# Unable to access camera feed in wechat browser

Tags: html, html5-video, webrtc, getusermedia, wechat

I am building custom camera view to capture documents or selfies using WebRTC API.

```
navigator.getUserMedianavigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia
```

My code is working fine in chrome, but when paste and open the same app link (https only) in wechat, it is failing. Since, I can't share my whole code, I am pasting some other link replicating the issue.
Below link is working fine in chrome but not in wechat, on the same Android device.
 https://davidwalsh.name/demo/camera.php

Does wechat has any restrictions to access camera video stream? How can wechat itself able to customize camera in its "Scan QR code" feature?

**Note:** I am not using wechat desktop/web version. In wechat mobile app, you can share your web application link with other friends/users. once user clicks the app link, wechat will open the link in built-in wechat browser. There by users can see your application in wechat browser. My issue is - my application shows custom camera, which is not appearing in wechat browser but in chrome. 
WeChat app already has camera permission.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome does not allow cross-origin getUserMedia request from an iframe, for it work wechat has to allow your url to access the media device. Check out [this](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/dev/Home/chromium-security/deprecating-permissions-in-cross-origin-iframes) for further info on this issue.

Comment: Looks like my question caused ambiguity, please see updated content now. Thanks for your time.